# Publish to artifactory and overwrite existing version with SBT

Tags: sbt, artifactory

Does anyone know how I overwrite a version when publishing to artifactory using sbt? When I currently run `sbt publish` it gives the below error but I don't know how to set it to true

```
java.io.IOException: destination file exists and overwrite == false
```

I've also tried setting `isSnapshot := true` but then I get the below error

```
PUT operation to URL <url> failed with status code 409: Conflict
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you publishing a snapshot version ? It should overwrite by default.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to give your Artifactory user `Overwrite` permissions.  See the [Managing Permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) documentation for details.